# update all datetime fields to date in Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any shortway to change all the `datetime` fields to `date` field in `SQL SERVER 2008 R2` using a single query,or something like that,I need to change all the `datetime` fields including fields in `table design` and `stored procedures` to `date` field.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sufficient permissions, you could do something like this by querying some system views and executing dynamic SQL. Fair warning, though -- if this isn't done extremely carefully, it could potentially really mess things up. Changing datatypes is the sort of thing that, tedious as it is, benefits from having a human to watch over it. My code should be taken as just an illustration, not to be just copied-and-pasted.

For table fields, you can use the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view to find `datetime` columns, then execute a DDL statement for each. That means you'll want to use a cursor, which is frowned upon for DML statements in production, but I think is generally fine for these sorts of DDL statements. I'm going to leave out a lot of the cursor code, since it's just the logic that's important here; if you need help writing that code, let me know.

To get the table and column names of all datetime columns:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE DATA_TYPE = 'datetime'
```

Then, use those to execute the some dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000);
SET @sql = N' ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@table_name)
             + N' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name)
             + N' date NULL';
EXEC @sql;
```

For stored procedures, you can get the entire text of the stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT m.definition
FROM sys.objects AS o
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS m
  ON o.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'P';
```

That will give you the text of each procedure's `CREATE PROCEDURE` command. You could then run something like this:

```
SET @definition = REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(@definition, 'CREATE PROCEDURE', 'ALTER PROCEDURE')
                    , 'datetime', 'date');
EXEC @definition;
```

Comment: This answer is a good start but changing column's data type requires DROP and [re]CREATE for dependable objects: default "constraints", check constraints, FK constraints, UNIQUE/PRIMARY KEY (constraints), indexes, if there are such objects. And, instead of `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` I would use `sys.columns`. More, I would consider if some columns are `is_nullable` 0 / 1 {`NOT NULL` / `NULL`}.